# Crystal Reports works via HTTP but not via HTTPS

Tags: azure, https, crystal-reports

I have searched every where (I think) and I have not been able to find the answer, maybe because it is so elementary but here goes.  I recently deployed a Silverlight Business Application to the Windows Azure platform.  I am using Crystal Reports for my reporting and everything was working fine.  I need to run the app in SSL, so I purchased a certificate and followed the instructions to get the app up and running and again everything works great except for the reports.  When I access the site with via http I have no problems printing my reports.  But via https I get the following when I attempt print a report:

> Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unsupported Operation. A
>   document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++
>   stack.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[COMException (0x80041811): Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +147
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +422
[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +549
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +1613
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) +189
   COCOBOLO.Web.Files.ReportHandler1.MeetingMinutes() +247
   COCOBOLO.Web.Files.ReportHandler1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2392
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

I am almost certain that there is a permission issue using Crystal Reports with SSL but I have no idea what to do.  Has anyone had this problem?  HELP PLEASE!

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  I have deployed the Silverlight app to Windows Azure and I have assigned one of the endpoints to port 443.  Is there a  way to open/close ports on the Azure platform?  Forgive me for my ignorance, this is all new to me.  Just to recap, everything works except Crystal Reports with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

since your stack trace shows that Load Report Failed, the first thing i would do is to check whether you have the report in your project and your code is able to access the report. 
i know everything works fine using HTTP. Also, make sure that you have read write permissions on the folder where you store your reports.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did check that the reports are in the project and that the code is able to access the report.  I am not sure about setting the permissions to the folder for a project being deployed to Azure, but if the project didn't have access, wouldn't I get an error in both cases? However, the ONLY thing I am changing when debugging is the Startup Action in the Azure WebRole properties.  When I select the HTTP endpoint, I can print with no problem.  When I select the HTTPS endpoint, I get the error.  This is the ONLY thing that I am changing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to test the theory that the load failure is due to not having access to the reports, I deliberately changed on of the reports to a name that KNOW does not exist, and as expected, the code failed here when it tried to load the report:            OrderReport = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ProjectMeeeetingMinutes.rpt");
            OrderReport.Load(reportPath);

Comment: When I changed the report name to an existing report it fails after the report has successfully loaded and all the connection string variables and report parameters have been verified:              OrderReport.ExportToHttpResponse(exportType, Response, true, "Meeeting Minutes");   So seems like exporting the report to the buffer so that a user can view the report is causing the error.  But I don't know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in your crystal report. the problem because ssl don't want to load pdf file.

[Display pdf in iframe using ssl/https based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072620/display-pdf-in-iframe-using-ssl-https-based)

you can try to download pdf viewer in chrome store it's work in ssl and for me.

best regard.