# Display pdf in iframe using ssl/https based

Tags: pdf, ssl, iframe, https, asp-classic

I want to Showing PDF inside iframe for user preview before download the file or print,

i use byte array convert my report file to pdf then showing it.

everything was perfect until i need something in ssl/https.

because of that i must change my application to ssl/https can some one show me how can i show pdf in this condition.

thanks for listening and reading my prob.

here my code

```
        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
        reportDocument.SetDataSource(dataSet);
        _contentBytes = StreamToBytes(reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
       .....
       //setting header
       .....

       //then flush
       stream.Flush();
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, the same code should work as long as you're using relative references or using the correct URL after checking if `Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = on`

Comment: nothing wrong with the code. my prob is only because ssl/https don't want to create preview file. in http everything is working because it want to load the pdf.

Comment: You had mentioned using an iframe do load the PDF file -- can you check if the iframe is also published with SSL? Your issue might be using SSL for the parent but not for the inside frame.

Comment: My iframe is already in ssl. I check the network then open the link to my report to open the pdf. It won't open. So i thing the main prob is in open pdf in ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution in 
[PDF conversion suddenly fails if reading stylesheet from SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260349/pdf-conversion-suddenly-fails-if-reading-stylesheet-from-ssl)
the problem is the pdf reader inside my chrome browser.
so i updating my chrome reader in store search pdf viewer..
just it..